# Webpage og:image are cropped in facebook

Tags: html, image, facebook-opengraph

I have `og:image` on my web page and image size 1200px by 630px. It gets cropped at on Facebook, what I miss!?

**CODE**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.url.com/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.url.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
```

Comment: I use a size of 600x300 and works fine

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem. You have probably edited the image several times and saved it with the same filename. The image is being cached on Facebook servers and Facebook does not refresh the image if the name remains the same. Rename your image and update your pages html then use [Facebooks Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

Comment: if this is still the case, wish this information was in docs.  spent over an hour trying the different sets of dimensions they define on various docs pages (eg 1080 x 1080, 1200 x 630, 1080 x 565), committing, pushing, rebuilding, clearing cloudflare cache etc, you would think the "scrape again" button on the debugger would grab the latest version from your server, not a cached version on their servers.  my image did have a white background though, so that could have played into it too, other info which would be helpful in the docs.  1200 x 630, black border, new filename worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

check if your picture's aspect ratio is 1.91:1, this aspect ratio is what facebook reccomends in order to avoid cropping.. check it out here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#, Good luck and hope it helps!!

Comment: 1200 x 630 is the recommended size from fb.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to following Facebook's [best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) for image sizing, be wary of white backgrounds around the edge of your image.  Facebook will automatically crop off white edges and use the cropped result. This will reduce the size and potentially change the dimensions of your image.

If you do need to pad out an image, you should use a colored or textured background to prevent cropping.